# Laravel Mix in Laravel 5.0 - Compatibility issues

Tags: php, laravel, webpack

I work in a pretty big code base currently in Laravel 5.0 and we don't have the time nor the resources to upgrade to Laravel 5.4 just yet. I tried to implement Laravel Mix into our repo with the following code:

webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix').mix;
mix.js('resources/assets/js/jQuery.js', 'public/js')
      .js('resources/assets/js/test.js', 'public/js');
      .less('resources/assets/test/app.less', 'public/css');
```

NEW FILE: assets/js/jQuery.js

```
global.$ = global.jQuery = require('jquery');
```

NEW FILE: assets/js/test.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   let variable = "World!";
   console.log(`Hello ${variable}`);
});
```

index.blade.php

```
@section('css')
    <link href="css/app.css" rel="stylesheet">
@show

@section('footer')
    <script src="/js/manifest.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/vendor.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/test.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/jQuery.js"></script>
@show
```

RUN in terminal:

```
npm install
npm run watch
```

It looks like it's working since my less and es6 files are being compiled. I also removed our CDN link to jQuery and replaced it with . All style changes are being applied, console logs are showing up, and jQuery is being loaded.

However, I'm getting errors on my console(see below)

```
GET ..../manifest.js   X  404 Not Found
GET ..../vendor.js      X  404 Not Found
```

If I remove links to them(manifest and vendor) on my index file, everything still works.

I've only spent a day with this code and would like to know if it's worth trying to debug? Or does the fact that I don't have Laravel 5.4 causing my issues? Does anybody know why all my other code are still working?

Comment: `Manifest.js` and `vendor.js` are generated when using `.extract` to split code from vendor libraries. You don't seem to be doing that.

Comment: Do you have laravel-mix added in your package.json ? e.g. 'dependencies': { ..., "laravel-mix": "0.*", .. )

Comment: Thank you for your help @Andy! I had it but didn't include it in my question.            
                             
Thank you @apokryfos! That fixed my issue.                      
                                          
Updated webpack.mix.js and now I don't have any console errors!                             
                                    
`mix.js('resources/assets/js/jQuery.js', 'public/js')
   .js('resources/assets/js/test.js', 'public/js')
   .extract(['jquery'])
   .less('resources/assets/test/app.less', 'public/css');`